# How to represent a function performed by the system?

Tags: requirements, use-case

In use case modelling, if I have functions that have to be done by the system itself (without actors), how can I represent them?

For example, sending SMS message, compute bus route, or notify someone when a change occur.

Comment: What triggers would there be to cause the system to perform those tasks?

Comment: when registering in the system an sms message will be sent to the user. each bus has a predefined bus route calculated by the system based on students assigned to that bus, and every time a student change or absent, a new route will be computed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function performed by the system is not a use case. It is an action which is part of a use case. A use case is some added value it's primary actor gets when applying the use case.

Answer (score -1):

You can represent them as use cases of sub-function level and performed by the system as primary actor.